# NetLogo read in file as list of characters

Tags: string, file-io, netlogo

I am new to NetLogo. I have a text file that has one row of values:

```
ABC
CDC
BBC
```

I am trying to read in the first line of that file as a list of characters (e.g. [A B C]), I have been trying to use file-read-line, but it creates a string "ABC" instead.

```
observer> file-open "test.txt"
observer> show file-read-line
observer: "ABC"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert each line from a string to a list. NetLogo has no primitive to do that directly, but it's relatively simple to write a reporter that does it:

```
to-report string-to-list [ s ]
  report ifelse-value empty? s
    [ [] ]
    [ fput first s string-to-list but-first s ]
end
```

And then:

```
observer> show string-to-list file-read-line
observer: ["A" "B" "C"]
```

Comment: `map [item ? s] n-values length s [?]` also works. I'm a little surprised I don't see this in https://github.com/NetLogo/String-Extension/