# How to filter only the unique scenarios in netlogo behavior space

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

I want to run a set of scenarios in netlogo using behavior space where n number of competing turtles use different decision rules. What i mean by that is lets say i want to measure a metric in a coin-toss scenario where each player is programmed to call heads or tails at every tick i.e. in a 2 turtle situation player A always call heads and player B always calls tails.

When the number of turtles is more than 3 there will cases where ABC or ACB or BCD will call heads while the other calls tails. In essence HHTH is the same as HHHT.

So what i want to do in short is to filter only for the unique occurences, without considering the position of H or T in the sample space i.e. I want only those cases where there is only 1H and 3T, 2H & 2T, 3H & 1T.

Thanks in advance for the help. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question as asked does not seem to involve behavior space.  To count the heads in a list use the `table` extension.  (The example you give is binary and has fixed length sequences, so the number of heads determines the number of tails, so you only need to count one of them.)

```
extensions [table]

to-report nHeads01 [#lst]
  let _t table:counts #lst
  report ifelse-value (table:has-key? _t "H") [
    table:get _t "H" ;case sensitive ...
  ][
    0
  ]
end
```

For example, we can generate some random sequences of length 4 (from your example) and filter for those with length 2 (or anything else).

```
to-report randomHT [#n]
  report n-values #n [[?] -> one-of ["H" "T"]]
end

to test
  let _xss n-values 20 [[?] -> randomHT 4] ;20 lists to filter
  print filter [[?] -> (2 = nHeads01 ?)] _xss ;print those with 2 heads
end
```

If you are storing the sequences as strings, you can install the string extension and `explode` the strings before using the above code, or you can follow [NetLogo read in file as list of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276700/netlogo-read-in-file-as-list-of-characters) to convert strings to character lists.  E.g.,

```
to-report nHeads02 [#str]
  let _lst map [[?] -> item ? #str] n-values length #str [[?] -> ?]
  report nHeads01 _lst
end
```